# Excel Pivot chart clears Data Labels when refreshed

Tags: excel, excel-charts, pivot-chart

I have two identical Pivot Charts (same chart template) on two different data sources. When I hit refresh all both have new data, first one with retained formatting and the second one is missing data labels (usually not all of them but randomly 1 or 2 sets out of 3 total data series). I don't want to mess the file with macros for chart formatting as all but one work just fine. 
Does anyone have any idea why there's such behavior? I have checked the options on both carths and are identical. 
All help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to switch the templates and see if the problem stays?

Comment: When I changed the template to a different one problem didn't occur. Still seems weird.